# Error when using Workbooks

Tags: excel, vba

I would like to develop a method to ensure that information is copied from 1 workbook (ThisWorkbook) and is pasted in another workbook (All data.xlsm) on empty rows. I was able to develop the code if the 2 sheets are in the same workbook, but now that I need to refer to another workbook it doesn't work (error 9). The difficulty is also that both workbooks are on a teamsite, but both files are open.
Please find below my code (with my best attempt).

```
Dim actionlogRow
Dim actionlogRowSet As Boolean
Dim RecordSave As String
Dim recordActionLog As String

actionlogRow = 1
actionlogRowSet = False

Application.ScreenUpdating = False

RecordSave = Range("new_actions").Cells(1, 1).Value

Workbooks("All data.xlsm").Activate

Do

    recordActionLog = Worksheets("Action Log").Range("C8:AE8").Offset(actionlogRow, 0).Cells(1, 1)

    If recordActionLog = "" Then
        'Location to copy to is current row
        actionlogRowSet = True
    Else
        'Look at next row
        actionlogRow = actionlogRow + 1
    End If

Loop Until actionlogRowSet = True

'Copy the record into the database
Call ThisWorkbook.Sheets("New actions").Range("new_actions_endorsed").Copy
Call Workbooks("All data.xlsm").Worksheets("Action Log").Range("C8:AE8").Offset(actionlogRow, 0).PasteSpecial(xlPasteValuesAndNumberFormats)

Application.ScreenUpdating = True
```

Comment: Is the file All data.xlsm inside the same folder as ThisWorksheet?

Comment: Which line causes the error? I assume it is this: Workbooks("All data.xlsm").Activate

Comment: Where is the sub located?  That is, is it in a regular module, in `ThisWorkbook`, or a sheet module?

Answer (score 0):

You must have both spreadsheets open in the same instance of Excel. If you open Excel first, then open both spreadsheets from that (Ctrl O) you should be fine. However if you open two Excel program files, they cannot see each other and you will get "Run-time error 9: Subscript out of range"